# How to add an additional existing environment via the Elastic Beanstalk CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a project that is configured via the Eb Cli, to monitor/publish a specific environment.

Now I want to add an additional environment/application to the project. This was already created manually.

How can I add it to the project? Tried running:

> eb init

But this just prompts a question:

> Do you wish to continue with CodeCommit? (Y/n)

When I choose "n", the process end and nothing happens.

How can an additional **existing** environment be wired to a project via the Eb Cli?